# Ambiguity in Roslyn's CompilationUnitSyntax.ReplaceNode

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to replace CompilationUnitSyntax of a class using Roslyn.

However, **ReplaceNode** that I'm using has a different signature than **ReplaceNode** in Roslyn FAQ and any StackOverflow question that I've looked at. Can anyone point out why is that, and how can I use **ReplaceNode** that takes *old ClassDeclarationSyntax* and *new ClassDeclarationSyntax* as parameters?

I'm looking at September CTP FAQ¹, method:

```
    [FAQ(26)]
    public void AddMethodToClass()
```

particularly the following line:

```
        CompilationUnitSyntax newCompilationUnit =
            compilationUnit.ReplaceNode(classDeclaration, newClassDeclaration);
```

When I'm attempting to build this code, I'm getting an error because ReplaceNode expects different arguments:

```
 'Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.CompilationUnitSyntax' does not contain a definition for 'ReplaceNode' and the best extension method overload
 'Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.SyntaxExtensions.ReplaceNode<TRoot>(TRoot,
 Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.SyntaxNode,
 Roslyn.Compilers.SyntaxRemoveOptions,
 System.Func<Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.SyntaxNode,Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.SyntaxTriviaList>,
 System.Func<Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.SyntaxNode,Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.SyntaxTriviaList>)'
```

¹ I'm fairly sure I'm using the September CTP:

I'm using the FAQ from *%userprofile%\Documents\Microsoft Roslyn CTP - September 2012\CSharp\APISampleUnitTestsCS\FAQ.cs*

NuGet says that my Roslyn package has version 1.2.20906.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two overloads of `ReplaceNode()` (both are extension methods):

1. ```
   public static TRoot ReplaceNode<TRoot, TNode>(
       this TRoot root, TNode oldNode, TNode newNode)
       where TRoot : CommonSyntaxNode where TNode : CommonSyntaxNode;
   ```

   in `Roslyn.Compilers.CommonSyntaxNodeExtensions`.
2. ```
   public static TRoot ReplaceNode<TRoot>(
       this TRoot root, SyntaxNode node, SyntaxRemoveOptions options, 
       Func<SyntaxNode, SyntaxTriviaList> keepLeadingTrivia = null,
       Func<SyntaxNode, SyntaxTriviaList> keepTrailingTrivia = null)
       where TRoot : SyntaxNode
   ```

   in `Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.SyntaxExtensions`.

You want the first one, but the error message talks about the second one, which indicates that you're missing `using Roslyn.Compilers;`.